# Is this polynomial $f$ in $\sqrt{J}$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, ring-theory, ideals

My problem Is the following:

> Let $f=(y+z)(x^3y+1)\in \mathbb{Q}[x,y,z]=:R$ and $J=(y-z, x^3y-1)$. I have to establish if $f\in\sqrt{J}$, i.e. if $\exists n \in\mathbb{N}$ such that $f^n\in J$.

I know that I could use the Radical Test but I'd like to avoid this way. My idea is to express $\sqrt J$ like intersection of prime Ideals (I know that this Is possible since $R$ Is noetherian).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is no: $(1,1,1)$ is a zero of the ideal, but $f(1,1,1)\ne 0$.

Comment: Yeah right! Thank you!